# связка PHP и 1С

Tags: php, 1с

Возникает ошибка при работе с 1С в php через soap

Php код:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$options = array(
  'login' => $username,
  'password' => $password,
  'exceptions' => 1,
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

print_r($client->__getFunctions());echo '<br>';
print_r($client->__getTypes());echo '<br>';

try{
  $client->GetOrder('test');
}
catch (SoapFault $s){
  echo $s->getMessage();
}
```

Результат:

```
Array ( [0] => GetOrderResponse GetOrder(GetOrder $parameters) [1] => GetOrderResponse GetOrder(GetOrder $parameters) )
Array ( [0] => struct GetOrder { all File; } [1] => struct GetOrderResponse { all return; } )
Неизвестная ошибка. Недостаточно параметров операции по причине: Недостаточно параметров операции
```

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:soap12bind="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
        xmlns:soapbind="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:tns="http://127.0.0.1"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsd1="http://127.0.0.1"
        name="HExchange"
        targetNamespace="http://127.0.0.1">
    <types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xs1="http://127.0.0.1"
                targetNamespace="http://127.0.0.1"
                elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xs:element name="GetOrder">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="File"
                                type="xs:all"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="GetOrderResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="return"
                                type="xs:all"
                                nillable="true"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="GetOrderRequestMessage">
        <part name="parameters"
                element="tns:GetOrder"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetOrderResponseMessage">
        <part name="parameters"
                element="tns:GetOrderResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="HExchangePortType">
        <operation name="GetOrder">
            <input message="tns:GetOrderRequestMessage"/>
            <output message="tns:GetOrderResponseMessage"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="HExchangeSoapBinding"
            type="tns:HExchangePortType">
        <soapbind:binding style="document"
                transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="GetOrder">
            <soapbind:operation style="document"
                    soapAction="http://127.0.0.1#HExchange:GetOrder"/>
            <input>
                <soapbind:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soapbind:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <binding name="HExchangeSoap12Binding"
            type="tns:HExchangePortType">
        <soap12bind:binding style="document"
                transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="GetOrder">
            <soap12bind:operation style="document"
                    soapAction="http://127.0.0.1#HExchange:GetOrder"/>
            <input>
                <soap12bind:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap12bind:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="HExchange">
        <port name="HExchangeSoap"
                binding="tns:HExchangeSoapBinding">
            <documentation> 
                <wsi:Claim xmlns:wsi="http://ws-i.org/schemas/conformanceClaim/"
                        conformsTo="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1"/>
            </documentation>
            <soapbind:address location="http://127.0.0.1:4880/UTP/ws/ws1.1cws"/>
        </port>
        <port name="HExchangeSoap12"
                binding="tns:HExchangeSoap12Binding">
            <soap12bind:address location="http://127.0.0.1:4880/UTP/ws/ws1.1cws"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: `Недостаточно параметров операции по причине: Недостаточно параметров операции` (c) 1C :)) А по теме, в документациях что написано про метод `GetOrder`? Ошибка ведь сама за себя говорит

Comment: я к сожалению не работал ранее с 1с или soap.
но если я правильно понимаю блок 
    <xs:element name="GetOrder">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="File"
                                type="xs:all"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
то метод должен принимать только 1 параметр.
И документации по нему нету - мне дали ссылку, по которой генерируется этот xml, и сказали что методу  GetOrder надо передавать файл

Comment: ну видимо файл, а так же то по чему его нужно сортировать? https://books.google.ru/books?id=quRbYxaQ8wcC&pg=PT207&lpg=PT207&dq=SoapClient+GetOrder+method+params&source=bl&ots=cbC6tzTB0L&sig=tIGvY7jHDhJU3uqNDXP5U75N4vc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjridfjg9LMAhXKHJoKHTVDAx0Q6AEILjAC
Ссылка с примером на книгу, что выдал гугл по использованию этого метода

Comment: File это название переменной... в перспективе туда надо xml файл передавать со списком заказов. Но тип type="xs:all" - должно принимать любой. А в примере, который вы дали, другая реализация метода с похожим названием. Эти методы создаются где то внутри 1с

Comment: Ну вам не хватает 1 параметра в этой строке `$client->GetOrder('test');`. Вам об этом интерпритатор и говорит. Если вы хотите получить отсортированный список, вам по любому нужны параметры сортировки. В примерах которые я видел везде нужно передавать xml с параметрами вида > `<params><param><key>...</key><value>..</value></param></params>`

Comment: ну, я уже пробовал передавать 15 параметров - результат не меняется)
да и xs:element только один

Comment: Может это поможет https://gist.github.com/benedict-w/4604789#file-neteven_webservice_examples-php-L140

Comment: не помогло - выдает ту же ошибку.
Может ли быть WSDL не рабочий?

Comment: как оказалось, на самом деле параметр не отправлялся:

    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://localhost">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetOrder />
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Не понятно почему php так сформировал запрос

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, надо было использовать SoapVar вместо простого вызова функции или SoapParam

Answer (score 0):

Как то давно это делал.
Я создал класс для работы из сайта с 1С 8:

Класс php **class.1c.php**

```
<?
    defined('1Cv8') OR die('Прямой доступ запрещён!');


    # Пример использования:
    #
    # 1. Создаём класс ::: $api = new api_1c();
    # 2. Устанавливаем соединение ::: $compound_SOAP = $api->connect();
    # 3. Выполняем запрос ::: $api->get($compound_SOAP, %Параметр%);
    #
    # Создаём класс для работы SOAP + 1С:Предприятие
    #   $api = new api_1c();            
    #   $compound_SOAP = $api->connect();
    #       
    # JSON параметр для 1С:Предприятие
    #   $data = array();
    #   $data['command'] = 'login';
    #   $data['user_name'] = 'admin';
    #   $data['user_password'] = 'admin';
    #
    # Выполним запрос
    #   $result = $api->get($compound_SOAP, json_encode($data));
    #
    # Проверим полученный результат, если результат обработан без ошибок
    #   if ($result['success']) {
    #
    #   $result['data']->return; - Это тело ответа 1С:Предприятие (Добовляем: '->return')
    #
    # Разбераем ответ и декадируем в массив PHP
    #   $structure = json_decode($result['data']->return, true);
    #
    #
    #############################################################################################
    #############################################################################################
    #
    #
    # Класс для соединение 1С:Предприятие 8 (WEB-Сервисы) WSDL
    #   
    # Возвращаемые параметры:
    #   Функция get возвращает двумерный массив массив
    #
    # Ключи:
    #
    # succes - true / false
    # data - результат
    # title - Заголовок (данный ключ формируются в случаи succes = false)
    # description - Описание (данный ключ формируются в случаи succes = false)
    # debug - Строковое значение результата для JS вывода в console
    #
    class api_1c {
        # Внутренняя переменная
        private $config;

        # Конструктор класса    
        public function __construct() {
            # Создаём класс конфигурации
            $CF = new config_XML();

            # Дополнительный контент API WSDL SOAP 1C
            $SOAP_server = $CF->get('1Cv8', 'Сервер'); # http://localhost/eta/ws/api.1cws?wsdl
            $SOAP_login = $CF->get('1Cv8', 'Пользователь'); # web
            $SOAP_password = $CF->get('1Cv8', 'Пароль'); # web
            $SOAP_debug = $CF->get('1Cv8', 'Использовать режим отладки'); # 1 или 0

            # Формируем параметры SOAP
            $CF_SOAP['login'] = "$SOAP_login";
            $CF_SOAP['password'] = "$SOAP_password";
            $CF_SOAP['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_2;
            $CF_SOAP['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
            $CF_SOAP['exceptions'] = true;
            $CF_SOAP['trace'] = true;
            $CF_SOAP['features'] = SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE; 
            # Собираем массив параметров в кучу    
            $this->config['SOAP'] = "$SOAP_server";
            $this->config['CF'] = $CF_SOAP;
            $this->config['debug'] = ($SOAP_debug == 1 ? true: false);
        } 

        # Подключаемся к web сервису
        public function connect() {
            # Результирующий массив
            $result = array();

            # Проверим подключенный модуль php-soap
            if (!function_exists('is_soap_fault')) {
                $result['success'] = false;
                $result['title'] = 'Ошибка сервера SOAP';
                $result['description'] = 'Не настроен web сервер. Не найден модуль php-soap.';
                return $result;
            }        

            try { # Попытка создать соединение
                # Создаём соединение с web сервисом 1С:Предприятие 8
                $SOAP = new SoapClient($this->config['SOAP'], $this->config['CF']);    
            } catch (SoapFault $e) { # Если ошибка
                $result['success'] = false;
                $result['title'] = 'Ошибка подключения';
                $result['description'] = 'Невозможно установить соединение с сервером ['. $e->getMessage() .']'; # $e;
                return $result;
            }

            # Если ошибка 
            if (is_soap_fault($SOAP)) {
                $result['success'] = false;
                $result['title'] = 'Внутренняя ошибка сервера';
                $result['description'] = 'Неопределенная ошибка сервера, повторите попытку';
                return $result;
            }

            # Возвращаем результат
            $result['success'] = true;
            $result['SOAP'] = $SOAP;
            $result['debug'] = $this->config['debug'];
            return $result;           
        }

        # Выполняем запрос и получаем ответ
        public function get($constructor, $options) {
            # Результирующий массив
            $result = array();

            # Если ошибок не обнаружено 
            if ($constructor['success']) {
                # Если тип ключа массива является объектом, то сформируем команду запроса
                if (is_object($constructor['SOAP'])) {

                    try { # Попытка выполнить команду на стороне 1С:Предприятие
                        $data = array();
                        $data['options'] = $options;

                        $result['success'] = true;
                        # Формируем команду 1С:Предприятие
                        # @Handle(Параметр) - является командой 1С:Предприятие
                        $result['data'] = $constructor['SOAP']->Handle($data); 

                        # Если включен режим отладки добавляем ключ (Для JS console)
                        if ($constructor['debug']) {
                            $result['debug'] = $result['data']->return;    
                        }

                        return $result;
                    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
                        $result['success'] = false;
                        $result['title'] = 'Ошибка';
                        $result['description'] = 'Невозможно выполнить операцию запроса';

                        # Если включен режим отладки добавляем ключ (Для JS console)
                        if ($constructor['debug']) {
                            $result['debug'] = $e;    
                        }

                        return $result; # var_dump($e);    
                    }   

                # Иначе если тип ключа массива не является объектом
                } else {
                    $result['success'] = false;
                    $result['title'] = 'Ошибка';
                    $result['description'] = 'Не удалося подключиться к 1С:Предприятие';

                    # Если включен режим отладки добавляем ключ (Для JS console)
                    if ($constructor['debug']) {
                        $result['debug'] = $result['description'];    
                    }

                    return $result;
                }

            # Иначе вернем ранее сформированный массив т.к. при подключении к WEB серверу были обнаружены ошибки
            } else { 
                return $constructor;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

И в 1С Web-сервисы > API > Handle

```
Функция Handle(options)

    ЧтениеJSON = Новый ЧтениеJSON;
    ЧтениеJSON.УстановитьСтроку(options);
    Параметр = ПрочитатьJSON(ЧтениеJSON);
    ЧтениеJSON.Закрыть();

    Ответ = ОбработатьДанныеДляОтвета(Параметр);

    Возврат Ответ;

КонецФункции

// Обработка входящих данных
// Параметры:
//  Параметры - Структура - Структура параметров
// Возвращаемое значение:
//  Ответ - Строка - Строка в формате JSON
// 
// Обязательные ключи в структуре возврата:
//  is - Строка - с двумя вариантами "error" - Ошибка; "success" - Данные успешно обработаны
//  title - Строка - Заголовок 
//  description - Строка - Описание
//
Функция ОбработатьДанныеДляОтвета(Параметры) Экспорт

    Ответ = Новый Структура;
    Ответ.Вставить("is", "error");
    Ответ.Вставить("title", "Ошибка обработки команды");
    Ответ.Вставить("description", "Команда не зарегистрирована в системе 1С:Предприятие");

    // Тут чего нибудь делаешь  

    ЗаписьJSON = Новый ЗаписьJSON;
    ЗаписьJSON.УстановитьСтроку();
    ЗаписатьJSON(ЗаписьJSON, Ответ);

    Возврат ЗаписьJSON.Закрыть();

КонецФункции
```